# Is it possible for a constructor to call itself?

Tags: java, object, constructor

Is it possible for a constructor to call a class which is related to it? For example (in the code below) I am trying to create a new clock with ClockTimer and call the AnalogClock construct which has a ClockTimer parameter type. It doesn't seem to work because it gives me an error, but creating a new AnalogClock with the ClockTimer parameter in the ClockFrame class appears to work. What do I need to parse in AnalogClock (in the ClockApp) in order for it to run?

Comment: If AnalogClock depends on ClockTimer and ClockTimer depends on AnalogClock it means you have a circular dependency. You cannot solve this situation in Java, so you need to find another way to circumvent this.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: @tgdavies I think it's obvious timer is being used before its declaration, so probably unknown symbol timer.

Comment: You could try and create the ClockTimer inside the AnalogClock constructor where the clock can pass itself.

Comment: You are not using `clockFrame` in the `ClockTimer` class, why don't you remove that field?

Comment: *Is it possible for a constructor to call itself?* what happens when you do it?

Comment: Error: java cannot find symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the outside, it looks like the "analogClock" object needs the "timer" object to exist first, and the "timer" object needs the "analogClock" object to exist first.
In reality, thought, "timer" doesn't do anything with the "analogClock" ("clockFrame" inside "ClockTimer"), so it actually doesn't need it.

I'd suggest the following:

1. Remove the "clockFrame" parameter and field inside "ClockTimer"
2. Create the "timer" object first
3. Create the "analogClock" object second, and pass "timer" to it